# Integral incomplete gamma:$\int_0^\infty x^{k-1} \frac{\gamma(x,t)}{\Gamma(x)} dx$, $k\in \{1,2,3...\}$ and $t>0$.

Tags: integration, analysis, improper-integrals, special-functions, gamma-function

I need to solve an integral involving the lower incomplete gamma $\gamma$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) and the Gamma function $\Gamma$.
In particular the integral is
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty x^{k-1} \frac{\gamma(x,t)}{\Gamma(x)} dx
\end{align*}
with $k\in \{1,2,3...\}$ and $t>0$.

Do you have any tip? Do you know any book that has similar results? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know about the [regularized lower incomplete gamma function $P(a,z)$ and upper $Q(a,z)$](https://www.wikidoc.org/index.php/Regularized_Gamma_function)? Your integral then is:$$\int_0^\infty x^{k-1} P(x,t)dx= \mathcal M_x\{P(x,t)\}(k)$$

which is just [The Mellin Transform](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform). Let [this expansion](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/GammaRegularized/06/01/05/01/01/0003/) be used:

$$ \mathcal M_x\{P(x,t)\}(k) =\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{k-1}t^x}{Γ(x+1)}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x t^n}{(x+n)n!}dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-t)^n}{n!}\int_0^\infty \frac{x^kt^x}{x!(x+n)}dx$$

Let’s try to use [Ramanujan’s Master Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_master_theorem):

$$\int_0^\infty x^{k-1} P(x,t)dx=Γ(k)\varphi(-k)$$

Where $\varphi(m)$ is a type of generating function for $P(x,t)$:

$$P(x,t)=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m x^m}{m!}\varphi(m)$$

Note that $$\varphi(m)\mathop=^\text{may}\varphi(m,t)$$

because of the $t$ parameter.
This integral looks almost like a [Mu function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MuFunction.html). Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: Thanks! But if we suppose that $x,t $ are real and positive, in particular $t>0$, can we say that $P(x,t)$ is analytic? Because if it is analytic, I have only to find the series representation and use Ramanujan's master theorem

Comment: @Otsuaf [Yes it is analytic](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/GammaRegularized/04/01/). Note that $$1-P(a,z)=Q(a,z)=\frac{Γ(a,z)}{Γ(a)}$$ Do you want a closed form or something else?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes, I'm looking for a closed formula so I'm looking for $\varphi$, the generating function of $P$. You have already done a lot for me, thank you again :)